# Cholesky decomposition of a $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I want to decompose the following matrix using Cholesky. I know that $R=LL^T$ where L is the lower-triangular, but I do not know how to find the lower-triangular or if that formula suffices for this matrix

$$R = \begin{pmatrix} 1.0 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\ 0.6 & 1.0 &0.6 & 0.4 \\ 0.4 & 0.6 & 1.0 & 0.6 \\ 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 1.0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I assume that $R = C$. You could start by finding the top left entry $L_{11}$ of $L$. Write down the equation that $L_{11}$ must satisfy and solve it.

Comment: What particular properties does a lower triangular matrix have? I thought this involved row operations of some sort.

Comment: http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/103/lectures/chol.pdf , http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~foster/m143m/cholesky.pdf

Comment: Your matrix is symmetric and positive defined, so you can use Cholensky decomposition.  For the algorithm  you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky_algorithm, or https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/04LinearAlgebra/cholesky/  for more examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R = $ $\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{21} & ... a_{n1} \\a_{21} & a_{22} & ... a_{n2} \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ... a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}$

$L$ is the lower triangular matrix,

$\begin{pmatrix} \ell_{11} & 0 & ...0_n \\ \ell_{21} & \ell_{22} & ...0_n \\ \ell_{31} & \ell_{32} & ...\ell_{3n} \end{pmatrix}$

$L^T$ is the transpose of the above matrix.

$\ell_{ki} = \frac{\large a_{ki} - \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \ell_{ij}*\ell_{kj}}{\huge\ell_{ii}}$

$\ell_{kk}= \sqrt{(a_{kk} -  \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (\ell_{kj})^2)} $